# Basis expansion using Koszul formula

Tags: linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry, tensors, orthogonality

Since the metric tensor is a symmetric bilinear form, it feels like I should be able to expand a vector like this:

$
Z = g(Z,e_k)e^k
$

Where the e_k together spans the space (maybe they need to be orthogonal wrt g, maybe g(e_k,e_k) need to be 1)

Now, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Riemannian_geometry:

$
g(\nabla_X Y,Z) = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_X(g(Y,Z)) + \partial_Y(g(X,Z)) -\partial_Z(g(X,Y)) + g([X,Y],Z) - g([X,Z],Y) - g([Y,Z],X))
$

Where ( I guess )

$
[X,Y](f) \equiv X(Y(f)) - Y(X(f))\equiv[\partial_X,\partial_Y](f)\\
\partial_X(F)(p) \equiv \lim_{t\to 0}t^{-1}[F(p+tX(p))-F(p)]
$

So, I wonder if I can find coefficients for $\nabla_X Y$ by doing this:

$\nabla_X Y = g(\nabla_X Y,e_k)e^k = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_X(g(Y,e_k)) + \partial_Y(g(X,e_k)) -\partial_{e_k}(g(X,Y)) + g([X,Y],e_k) - g([X,e_k],Y) - g([Y,e_k],X))e^k$